# Python error handling not working as intended

Tags: python, error-handling, python-os

The below code is meant to handle an error and keep trying until it succeeds. Very rarely a FileNotFound error will be thrown (I can see them in console) but in these cases it doesn't seem to be trying again, as I do not get a new image when the error trips.

```
saved = False
while not saved:
        saved = True
        try:
            os.rename(imagePath, savePath)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            saved = False
```

Comment: Maybe try doing it the other way around? `saved = False` initially, and then `saved = True` just after `os.rename()`, before the `except` block. And put a `continue` in the `except` block.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy even more idiomatic in Python, skip the "saved" flag altogether and use just `while True` breaking the loop when operation succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

I dare to say almost every `while` loop in Python that is not `while True` is a code smell. This is untested but should nudge you in the right direction:

```
max_retries = 10
retry_time = 0.1
retries = 10

while True:
    retries += 1
    try:
         os.rename(image_path, save_path)
    except FileNotFoundError:
         time.sleep(retry_time)  # lets avoid CPU spikes
    else:
         break  # Everything OK, lets move on
    if retries > max_retries:
         # We don't want to get stuck if for some reason the file
         # is deleted before we move it or if it never arrives.
         msg = f"Failed to move {image_path} to {save_path} after {retries} times."
         raise Exception(msg)  # or log the event and break the loop
```

There are several options of "retry" decorators for Python, try to google "python retry decorator".